# setRequestHeader not working in enyo.xhr.request

Tags: enyo

I am working on enyo.xhr. To create a request, i am using enyo.xhr.request with parameters having url and type of method. But i am facing problem while setting the requestHeader to some range of bytes. 
It is showing an error having "xhr object is no longer usable".
I have checked that it is possible with XmlHttpRequest() using setRequestHeader() with parameter as Range and passing the respective value. But how could we set the Request header using enyo.xhr.request().

Comment: can you post your exact code?  You might get a quicker answer on the EnyoJS forums (forums.enyojs.com)

Answer (score 0):

xhr for Post request:

```
var xhr = enyo.xhr.request({url:url,method:'POST', 
      headers:{"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, 
      body: reqBody ,sync:false});
```

where:
URL is some URL,
reqBody is baseString,

Can include as many headers you want?

Has this answered your question?